# Best way to check if a field is empty in a DTL

Tags: intersystems, intersystems-ensemble

For a non repeating field.  How do I write an If that executes only if the field is empty.

i.e. source.{PID:19}

I've tried source.{PID:19} = "" and source.{PID:19} '= "" in the if (With true and false), but neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `..Length(source.{PID:19})>0` which worked.  Thought I had tried this before.